# Getting sum in zend

Tags: zend-framework

trying to get value1 * value2

```
$wTrakcie = $pozycja->select('SUM(ilosc * cenaSprzedazy) AS sum')
        ->from('pozycja',array())
        ->join('preorder',array())    
    ->where('preorder.sprzedawca_id = ?',$sprzedawca_id) 
        ->where('preorder.preorder_id = pozycja.preorder_id')     
        ->setIntegrityCheck(false);    
    $wynik = $pozycja->fetchAll($wTrakcie);
        return $wynik->sum;
```

but I got

```
Notice: Undefined property: Zend_Db_Table_Rowset::$sum in C:\xampp\htdocs\spms\application\models\DbTable\Pozycja.php on line 29
```

what's the problem?

query is correct!

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look like:

```
$wTrakcie = $pozycja->select()
                    ->from('pozycja', array('sum' => 'SUM(ilosc * cenaSprzedazy)'))
                    ->join('preorder', array())    
                    ->where('preorder.sprzedawca_id = ?', $sprzedawca_id) 
                    ->where('preorder.preorder_id = pozycja.preorder_id')     
                    ->setIntegrityCheck(false);

$wynik = $pozycja->fetchRow($wTrakcie);
return $wynik->sum;
```